# Grouped styled tableview in detailview of splitview

Tags: ipad, uitableview, uisplitview

I try to have a grouped styled tableview in the right view of my splitview (DetailViewController). The DetailViewController has a UITableViewController without NIB file. I already have implemented

```
 - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
   if ((self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped])) {
   }
   return self;
  }
```

With no effect. Maybe I have to override -(id)init{}?

Any help would be nice. regards Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I just solved it. In MainWindow-iPad.xib I put an UITableViewController on the spot of the UIViewController of the right panel. With this controller comes a Tableview. First i switched the name of the class to DetailViewController.  Then I linked all outlets and delegates. Finally I set the style to grouped of this tableview in IB. And that worked.